# Latest WAS Liberty MQ connection with SSL certificate

Tags: ibm-mq, websphere-liberty

Guys I am trying to connect to MQ Hub from WAS Liberty application. Our MQ Hub supports only SSL certificate authentication. I have created QCF, Keystore with JKS file and with certificate inside it. Then I created defaultSSLConfig and pointed to that keystore.

But I could not find anyway to specify the SSLConfig in the QCF and read on some page that it was not possible. The only way was to use defaultSSLConfig and specify keystore from there which I did. So now I am here and MQ connection does  not work. On the MQ Hub logs I see the error saying that "The channel is lacking a certificate to use for the SSL handshake."

This is how my QCF looks like, no parameter to specify an SSL config

```
<jmsConnectionFactory connectionManagerRef="ConMgr" jndiName="jms/wmqCF">
         <properties.wmqJms channel="TEST_CHANNEL" hostName="REMOVED" port="1415" queueManager="ALQ.TEST" transportType="CLIENT" sslCipherSuite="SSL_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA"/>
    </jmsConnectionFactory>
```

Full error on MQ side

> EXPLANATION:
>   The channel is lacking a certificate to use for the SSL handshake. The
>   channel
>   name is 'XXX.ADM.SVRCONN' (if '????' it is unknown at this stage in the 
>   SSL
>   processing).
>
> The remote host is 'XXX (10.xx.xx.x)'.
>
> The channel did not start.
>   ACTION:
>   Make sure the appropriate certificates are correctly configured in the
>   key
>   repositories for both ends of the channel.
>
> ### ----- amqccisa.c : 7355
>
> 02/14/17 15:07:44 - Process(7510.304808) User(mqm) Program(amqrmppa)
>                       Host(xxx) Installation(Installation1)
>                       VRMF(7.5.0.6) QMgr(XXXXX)
>
> AMQ9999: Channel 'XXX.ADM.SVRCONN' to host 'xxx (10.xx.xx.xx)' ended
>   abnormally.
>
> EXPLANATION:
>   The channel program running under process ID 7510 for channel 'XX.ADM. 
>   SVRCONN'
>   ended abnormally. The host name is 'xx (10.xx.xx.xx)'; in some
>   cases the
>   host name cannot be determined and so is shown as '????'.
>
> ACTION:
>   Look at previous error messages for the channel program in the error
>   logs to
>   determine the cause of the failure. Note that this message can be
>   excluded
>   completely or suppressed by tuning the "ExcludeMessage" or
>   "SuppressMessage"
>   attributes under the "QMErrorLog" stanza in qm.ini. Further information 
>   can be
>   found in the System Administration Guide.

Comment: I have tagged the question as you suggested. The error I get on the MQ HUB side is the one I mention in the question. I dont see this as a MQ Hub problem but rather the implementation of the QCF in the Liberty. Have traditional WAS ND installations that work fine with the same MQ HUB using SSL cert authentication. It is WAS Liberty that is not working.

Comment: Here is what IO see on MQ side. Look at the original message, I updated it.

Comment: When you say MQ Hub do you mean Message Hub?

Comment: Yes, Its coming shortly. Trying to put it together. :)

Answer (score 1):

It is working now :) What we think was the cause of the problem is this bug  http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1IT16056

Although the error in APAR above is not the same I was getting. I was seeing this error on the Liberty (client side)

Caused by: com.ibm.mq.MQException: JMSCMQ0001: IBM MQ call failed with
compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2059' ('MQRC_Q_MGR_NOT_AVAILABLE').
at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.createException(Reason.
java:203)

I was using this resource adapter when the problem was manifesting itself:  9.0.1.0-IBM-MQ-Java-InstallRA.jar
Then we decided to try lower version of the adapter which had that APAR/fix in it and thus used this one: 8.0.0.6-WS-MQ-Java-InstallRA.jar

So that solved the problem.

I was pretty sure that the above bugfix was included in Ver 9.X of the resource adapter but as it turns out it is not the case.

Comment: 9.0.1.0 is in the 9.0 CD (continuous delivery) stream.  IBM has a issue with APARs showing 9.0.0.1 as the fixpack level for CD when it should show something like 9.0.1 or 9.0.2.  I have a PMR open with them and they are in the process of correcting this in the APAR descriptions, so it could possibly be that this was not fixed in 9.0.1.

Answer (score 1):

I checked with IBM and they confirmed that APAR [IT16056](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1IT16056) is not included in the 9.0.1.0 CD release.  They are working to correct the APAR to show the right target release for the fix.

Quote from IBM support is below.

> I can confirm that the APAR in question, "IT16056" is NOT included in 
>   the 9.0.1.0 CD release, and is currently targeted to be included in
>   the 9.0.2.0 CD release.

Based on this if you want you use a version of the RA higher than 8.0 you would need to do one of the following:

1. Wait until the 9.0 LTS (Long Term Support) 9.0.0.1 fixpack is released (IBM has a site where they list they are targeting 1Q 2017).
2. Wait until the 9.0 CD (Continuous Delivery) 9.0.2.0 release is out (IBM does not publish a target for CD)
3. Open a PMR to IBM and ask them for a IFIX to apply the 9.0.0.1 LTS or 9.0.1.0 CD release.

Comment: Thanks for checking. This explains it. I will wait for the next fixpack release.